# Limit the number of form submissions

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to set up registration forms for training but limit class size. I know the date/time limit but that won't work for limiting the number of participants.

Is there a way to stop accepting forms once a set number have been received?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the total number of submitted entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by setting [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/quantity-limits) on your form:

1. Add a *Calculation* field to the bottom of your form
2. Set **Calculation** to *Registration*
3. Set **Quantity Limits** to *Specific Quantity*
4. Set **Quantity** to *20*
5. Set **Error Message** to *Registration is full!*
6. Set **Show This Field** to *Never*

This will limit the total number of submitted registrations and show an error message to anyone trying to view/submit the form once registration is full.  If you later delete a registration, this will automatically open up registration slots.

[image]

If you have multiple classes with different limits, you can simply select *Limit Quantities* on the *Choice* field and specify the number of participants per class.  You can [learn more about quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/18/building-forms/limiting-quantities) in our help documentation.